# How to connect a Dealer socket to multiple Router sockets?

Tags: c#-4.0, zeromq

I'm currently using c# for a certain project. My protocol requires a request sent by the dealer socket and a reply is always sent by the router.

I create a single dealer for every router i need to connect to. The router bind() while the dealer connect().

Is it possible to connect a single dealer to multiple Routers?   How is it possible because a single connect() would require a disconnect() and the connect to next router? If it is disconnected how it will get the reply from the first router?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect a dealer to multiple routers.  Just call connect for each router.  You do not need to disconnect from the first to connect to the second.

Per [the docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-socket) "Each message sent is round-robined among all connected peers, and each message received is fair-queued from all connected peers."

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what if I want to choose, that is, I want to send specific messages to specific router. So how can I choose which router should receive the messages?

Comment: In that case you'd need to use 2 dealer sockets (1 connected to each router), and use application logic to choose which one to send with.

Comment: if there are dealer and router sockets but the dealer hasn't yet connected to the router. Can a router initiate a connection? A router needs some unique id for the dealer before it can send the message so how will it handle this particular case?